# Is there a program that finds the most optimal database indexes based on your code (C# for example)?

Tags: c#, database, automation

I know there are programs that give you a selection of indexes based on your database schema, but I can't find any that do it based on your code (i.e. based on what tables are accessed in queries the most). I mean, if in C# you opt for the code-first approach and Entity Framework handles the database, does someone start manually re-reading the code or watching the server-side requests for more optimal indexes, or you just don't care, since EF does a good enough job with the default schema?

Am I just not finding them or is there a huge and obvious reason (besides not wanting to disclose your code to third parties) that there are virtually none?

Comment: The huge and obvious reason is that the *code* plays little to no role at all. It's the *SQL queries* that matter and the data statistics. Not just the queries themselves, but how often they run, what they do etc. A slow reporting query that runs every midnight doesn't matter as much as a so-so update query that runs several times from multiple machines during business hours. The second is the one that causes blocking and noticeable delays

Comment: Besides, databases serve *many* applications and need to be optimized for all of them. The business's priorities won't be the same as an individual application's either. Databases, especially SQL Server, already offer optimization tools. SQL Server offers a query analyzer since the 90s that can test and find the optimal indexes for a query or set of queries. Indexes themselves are expensive, so adding more of them can end up causing extra delays.

Comment: SQL Server also offers management views and SSMS reports with missing indexes identified by the query engine when executing a query.

Comment: BTW the same query, same indexes will behave very differently on a table with 1000 rows and a table with 1M rows with different value distributions. A column with 1000 random values may look like a good candidate for indexing, but a column with 99000 identical and only 1000 different values is almost useless. That's another reason you need to optimize for the actual data, you can't just optimize based on the queries and test data

Comment: I think the way to do this would be to run your application, e.g. under a load test, and generate some traffic while profiling. Then use the profiler trace for optimization.